# Select neighbour faces from a mesh with python

Tags: python, bmesh, faces

I am new to blender and python and try to get the hang of it. PS: Everything should be achieved via python script.

I want to create a low poly model via ico-sphere. That's really easy because I just need to create a ico-sphere. Now I want to randomly select a face and one of his neighbours to merge them via bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add() to a new face.

I am having the following script:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') # into edit mode
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT') # deselect everything
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (True , False , False) # only faces
mesh=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me) # get mesh
mesh.faces.ensure_lookup_table() # update faces
mesh.faces[0].select = True # select face number 0
mesh.faces[1].select = True # select face number 1
bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add() # merge them
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT') # deselect everything
```

At first I am using bmesh which is experimental. I would like to use a blender api which isn't experimental. Any ideas?
I tried it with faces[0] and 1 and it worked, they are neighbours. But I think that's not always. How can I find out which faces are next to faces[0] for example.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

does his help? Start with the template in:

- TextEditor > Templates > Python > Bmesh Simple Editmode

---

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

face = bm.faces[3]
face.select = True
print(dir(face.verts[0].link_faces))
print(face.verts[0].link_faces[:])

# This gives the list of all edges that use that vertex.
# [<BMFace(0x7f7acb5ddb70), index=52, totverts=4>,    
#  <BMFace(0x7f7acb5ddbe0), index=54, totverts=4>,
#  <BMFace(0x7f7acb5ddba8), index=53, totverts=4>,  
#  <BMFace(0x7f7acb5dd0b8), index=3, totverts=4>]

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

There's also `link_edges` which could also prove useful, arguably more so

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# just assume now there is only one selected face
selected_face = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select][0]

for edge in selected_face.edges:
    linked = edge.link_faces
    for face in linked:
        face.select = True

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

produces

[image]
[image]

And finally, the join command

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# just assume now there are at least 2 selected, and are touching
selected_faces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select]

# the script equivalent of the F key        
bmesh.ops.contextual_create(bm, geom=selected_faces)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

[image]

Regarding your statement about Bmesh being experimental, I wouldn't worry about that too much, it's being used a lot and has proven to be more than capable. The [Bmesh.ops docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bmesh.ops.html) are an excellent but admittedly terse resource:

Comment: Wow, Thanks! That helped a lot! :) One thing I am a bit puzzled is the bmesh.ops.contextual_create(bm, geom=selected_faces), which is equivalent to bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add(). Why are there two methods which are doing the same? What is more correct? contextual_create or edge_face_add()?

Comment: `bpy.ops.*` and `bmesh.ops.*` are different routes to operate on meshes. The two functions you mention may be in some way equivalent, but if you have a reference to a bmesh, then you don't use bpy.ops. Think of bmesh as a virtual Mesh until you call update_edit_mesh on it. Whereas `bpy.ops.*` requires the mesh directly. I've probably not explained that very well... sorry.

Comment: Naaah, you don't need to apologize. Thanks for helping! I will try it right now :-)

Comment: Thank you! It's working but I need to call mesh.faces.ensure_lookup_table(). I think it is because I create the object a few lines above in my script.

Comment: yeah, i didn't want to potentially complicate a simple example.

Comment: I am having a problem :/ I have a uvsphere and randomly merge two faces which are next to each other. At first i thought everything worked but than I saw that the face isn't complete? It is more a triangular face and therefore the sphere has a hole. Looks like it is using only 3 vertices of each mesh instead of all 4. Can I upload a picture in the comment section?

Comment: @Michael - ask a new question, include the script you are using, and describe the end result you are trying to achieve (preferably with a screenshot or 'artists impression' of what it should look like )

Comment: the Blender.Stackexchange format works best when it solves one problem at a time, that way the Question description can help others find answers to similar small problems.

Comment: @Michael if you are merging two adjacent faces of a UV sphere, they are not co-planar.. try doing it without a script.. it probably looks wonky.