# Getting the number of faces a certain vertex is part of

Tags: python, bmesh

I am in edit mode and using bmesh to get all faces. I am iteration through the faces and their vertices. Now I want to know on how many faces the vertex, I currently have, is part of.

For example this green vertex is part of many faces.

[image]

Right now I have:

```
for f in mesh.faces:
    for v in f.verts:
        # some stuff before
        # now I need the number of faces the vertex c is part of
        # some other stuff
```

I know I could simply run through all faces and save the coordinates of the vertices and compare them with other faces and their coordinates - but maybe this can be done more easily.

Thanks!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28934/select-neighbour-faces-from-a-mesh-with-python?rq=1

Comment: Uh, you are right, the link_faces were there, too! I knew this was similar but haven't found it while skipping over it. Sorry! I still am learning.

Comment: it's OK, it might better to have some overlap in questions, because there are many ways to ask a question, even if the answer is similar to all. Search results become better by directing to fewer related results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a very nice feature of bmesh :)

```
import bpy
import bmesh

me = bpy.context.object.data


# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.new()   # create an empty BMesh
bm.from_mesh(me)   # fill it in from a Mesh

for f in bm.faces:
    for v in f.verts:
        lf = v.link_faces
        print('num faces:', len(lf), 'faces: ', lf[:])
    break
```